# Unable to select table from url

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble to select a table (or actually anything) from the specified URL. I used `find_all` method to no avail. There are multiple tables on the webpage separated by `<h3>` tags (image below is a table with `<h3>` tag 'Basic').

[image]

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


res = requests.get('Example_URL')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
print(table)
```

I expect to be able to select the table and then print the contents onto the console. But `print(table)` returns `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: first, if I see `<table>` tags, it's easier to use pandas to do the parsing (as it uses bs4 under the hood. It'll return a list of dataframes `tables = pd.read_html(url)`. But, this looks like it's a dynamic webpage, meaning the tables aren't actually in the source html, they are rendered after. So you'd need to do 1 of the follwong: 1) use Selenium to let the page render first, then pull the html, 2) sometime the table can be embeded as a json structure with the html (usually found under `<script>` tags, 3) see if there's a n API endpoint to directly pull that data/table

Comment: Hey, thanks fo the reply. There is indeed data in the HTML after the page renders as i can navigate further down the HTML tree and see the contents of the table. Note that i am using Selenium to get to this page after first logging into the page and then select the Expression of Interest hyperlink. The requests.get URL is then exactly the same URL that is shown in the active webpage.

Comment: use `driver.page_source` instead of request after `select the Expression of Interest hyperlink` This will return html of the page and then you can search `table` using BeautifulSoup

Comment: as stated above, if you are using selenium, you need selenium to get the html with `driver.page_source`. In your code above, you have `requests` getting that html. what I would do is `tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)`